# issue in dataframe series merge in python

Tags: python

i have two dataframes and i am trying to merge those but i am getting error.
below is my code:

source input

```
def source_input():
    global df1
    try:
        src_input = pd.DataFrame().assign(table_name=myconn.df_input['src_table_name'],
                                      column_name=myconn.df_input['src_column_name'],
                                      business_key_name=myconn.df_input['src_business_key_name'],
                                      select_column_names=myconn.df_input['src_select_column_names'],
                                      where_condition=myconn.df_input['src_where_condition'])
        src_input["schema_name"] = lsrcdbschemaname
        src_input["schema_table"] = src_input["schema_name"] + "." + src_input["table_name"]
        loging(datetime.datetime.now(), '-1', src_input)
        sql = 'select ' + src_input["column_name"] + ' as src_pk_clmn from ' + src_input['schema_table']

        df1 = sql[sql.notna()].apply(lambda i: pd.read_sql_query(i, db_conn))
        return df1
```

source output

```
0      src_pk_clmn
0      sonali
1      monika
2   ...
dtype: object
```

target input:

```
def target_input():
    global df2
    tgt_input = pd.DataFrame().assign(table_name=myconn.df_input['tgt_table_name'],
                                      column_name=myconn.df_input['tgt_column_name'],
                                      business_key_name=myconn.df_input['tgt_business_key_name'],
                                      select_column_names=myconn.df_input['tgt_select_column_names'],
                                      where_condition=myconn.df_input['tgt_where_condition'])
    tgt_input["schema_name"] = ltgtdbschemaname
    tgt_input["schema_table"] = tgt_input["schema_name"] + "." + tgt_input["table_name"]
    #print(tgt_input)
    try:
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
        sql = 'select ' + tgt_input["column_name"] + ' from ' + tgt_input['schema_table']
        df2 = sql[sql.notna()].apply(lambda i: pd.read_sql_query(i, db_conn))
        return df2
```

target output

```
1      FIRSTNAME
0    sonali
1    monika
2       SI...
```

```
def merge():
    df3 =pd.merge(df, df2, \
             left_on=["src_pk_clmn"], \
             right_on=["FIRSTNAME"], \
             how='outer')
    return(df3)
```

when i merge these two output i am getting error: **ValueError: Cannot merge a Series without a name**

My expectation is output should display like below. Please suggest me better way to achieve this.

```
0      src_pk_clmn   FIRSTNAME
0      sonali        sonali
1      monika        monika
2      sid           null
3      rahul         Rahul
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether df and df2 are really DataFrames or maybe rather series? Then your names are a bit misleading. In the later case, it might be simple - just give rach series a name before merging.

Comment: df1 and df2 are Series. i think because of "sql[sql.notna()].apply(lambda i: pd.read_sql_query(i, db_conn))" it become series

Comment: when giving name to series and thn do merge it give error.
df1 = pd.Series(sql[sql.notna()].apply(lambda i: pd.read_sql_query(i, db_conn)), name ='src_clm')   ,did same way for target df2.

df3 =pd.merge(df, df2, \
             left_on=["src_pk_clmn"], \
             right_on=["FIRSTNAME"], \
             how='outer')
error:
KeyError: 'FIRSTNAME'

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to use `concat`, not `merge`.

```py
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis='columns')
```

Comment: using concat output is not as expected.  output :```concat
                                                   0
1    FIRSTNAME
0    sonali
1    monika
2       SI... ```

Comment: When I do it, I get basically your expected output. The index is different than what you posted, and it has column names of 0 and 1; are those your issues? I can't get a sense of the shape of your result in the comment here. Did you do `axis='columns'` or `axis=1` (those will do the same thing). If you don't have the `axis` argument it'll just 'stack' them, so you'll have more rows instead of more columns

Comment: used below staement
df3 = pd.concat([df,df2],axis='columns')it only give me df2 output. zero as header i guess and 1 FIRSTNAME as row.
```
                                                 0
1    FIRSTNAME
0    sonali
1    monika
2       SI...
```  
column names are src_pk_clmn and FIRSTNAME

Comment: ah, my bad - your first df is `df1`, i just had df without the 1 on it. try with `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)`

Comment: concat is not working as expected it just combine. but my expectation is different.
0      src_pk_clmn   FIRSTNAME
0      sonali        sonali
1      monika        monika
2      sid           null
3      rahul         Rahul